# how to update Sonata getFlashMessage and addStatusService deprecations

Tags: php, symfony, updates, sonata, symfony-sonata

I'm updating a project from `sf2.6/php5.6` to `sf3.4/php7.1` and I'm actually facing these 2 deprecation errors:

```
Method "StatusExtension::addStatusService()" is deprecated since SonataCoreBundle 3.x and will be removed in 4.0. Use the StatusRuntime instead.
```

and

```
Method "FlashMessageExtension::getFlashMessages()" is deprecated since SonataCoreBundle 3.x and will be removed in 4.0. Use the FlashMessageRuntime instead.
```

I searched everything for these function calls and found a few, but none of them are actually in our codebase:

```
./vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/src/Twig/Extension/*.php
./vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/src/DependencyInjection/Compiler/StatusRendererCompilerPass.php
```

what do I have to update in order to prevent these deprecation messages? I have to get rid of them for further migrating to sf3.4 but can't figure out how to fix these.

as always, help is much appreciated

further information:

```
sonata-project/admin-bundle              3.39.0             
sonata-project/block-bundle              3.12.1             
sonata-project/cache                     2.0.1              
sonata-project/core-bundle               3.11.2             
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle           2.3.1             
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions       1.0.2              
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.4.2              
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle       2.5.0              
sonata-project/exporter                  1.9.1              
sonata-project/formatter-bundle          3.5.0              
sonata-project/intl-bundle               2.5.0              
sonata-project/jquery-bundle             1.10.2             
sonata-project/markitup-bundle           2.1.0              
sonata-project/media-bundle              3.15.0  

twig/extensions                          v1.5.2             
twig/twig                                v2.5.0
```

edit:

I'm using the newest version of the sonata core-bundle so I can't just update the most obvious package... I already did that.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Did you resolve that?

Comment: i also migrated sonata overall to the newest versions compatible with sf3.4

Comment: in other words you can ignore these two, they will auto resolve along the way